# Codechef: Problem name: Ups and Downs Problem code: ANUUND

Tags: python

I tried developing the following code solution for this problem (https://www.codechef.com/problems/ANUUND?tab=statement)

My solution code looks quite right to me and i tried some testcases manualy, which were giving correct answers. but the codechef gives this as incorrect on submission.
Kindly guide me about what's wrong and what am i missing:

```
    t = int(input())
    while t>0:
        n = int(input())
        x = list(map(int, input().split()))
        x.sort()
        new = []
        o =int(n/2)
        if n == 1:
            new.append(x[0])
        elif n%2 == 0:
            i = 0
            j = o
            k = 0
            while(k<n):
                if k%2 == 0:
                    new.append(x[i])
                    i = i+1
                else:
                    new.append(x[j])
                    j = j + 1
                k = k + 1
        else:
            i = 0
            j = o+1
            k = 0
            while(k<n):
                if k%2 == 0:
                    new.append(x[i])
                    i = i+1
                else:
                    new.append(x[j])
                    j = j + 1
                k = k + 1
        print(new)
     t = t - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue is that you are not following the output format they required. From the problem statement:

> For each test case, output a single line containing N space separated integers, which are the elements of A arranged in the required order.

However, you are printing the list `print(new)`, which for the first test case prints out '[2, 3]'. By simply changing the print statement to `print(' '.join([str(x) for x in new]))`, this prints out '2 3', as required. I was able to pass all the test cases with this modification.